# ¿Cómo mostrar elementos en una fila con el mismo alto (inline) dentro de página web?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Necesitó mostrar en una fila elementos HTML (Un TextBox, dos calendarios y u boton) escribí este código, pero tiene detalles que muestro en la imagen abajo.

¿Qué puedo hacer para corregirlo?

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:8%; display:inline-block;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" runat="server" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
          <input type="date" id="init" value="" min="" max="" class="form-control" runat="server">
          <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
          <input type="date" id="end" value="" min="" max="" class="form-control" runat="server">
          <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
          <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-success" runat="server" style="width:180px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me atreví a agregar una plantilla de `bootstrap` a tu código para mostrar una vista previa en el snippet y al parecer no hay problema. Asegúrate de no tener estilos personalizados en tu código.

Answer (score 2):

hola para eso te sirve las propiedades flex css osea

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:8%;display:inline-block;">
  <div class="row" >
      <div class="form-group col-12 d-flex justify-content-star align-items-start" style="heigth: 2rem;">
         <div class="input-group">
              <input  type="text" id="search" class="form-control" runat="server"/>
               <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
               <input  type="date" id="init" value="" min="" max="" class="form-control" runat="server" >
               <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
                <input  type="date" id="end"  value="" min="" max="" class="form-control" runat="server" >
               <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
              <input  type="button" id="btnSearch"  value="Buscar"  class="btn btn-success" runat="server"  style="width:180px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Me imagino que usas Bootstrap, esos son clases de Bootstrap en caso de que este ejemplo no funcione te invito a visitar [Flex Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/) para que obtengas toda la info, ademas otra forma seria

aunque yo re-estructuraria ese codigo y tratara de incrustarlo en Grillas lo que te da mas accesibilidad